# Proof of the semigroup property of the Brownian motion.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, semigroup-of-operators

Below is the proof on the semigroup property of the Brownian motion given in Schilling's Brownian Motion.

Let $B_t$ be a $d$- dimensional Brownian motion, and $u$ is a bounded Borel measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$. I'm having difficulty understanding the second equality below. The author uses $(6.4)$ for the step, however, I don't understand how we can get it from this. Namely, in the (6.4) provided below, we have the expectation taken over the probability space $P^0$, that is, where the Brownian motion starts at $0$. However, since we have $E^x$ in the setting of this problem, wouldn't we get $E^{B_s + x} [u(B_t)]$ from the (6.4)? How can I rigorously understand this step? I would greatly appreciate any help.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $W_t =  B_t - x$ the translated copy of $B$ that starts at $0$, and $v(y) = u(x+y)$.  Then we have
$$  \newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F} \newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E} \E^{B_0 =x}(u(B_{t+s}) | \F_s) = \E^{B_0=x}(u(x+W_{t+s}) | \F_s)) = \E^{W_0 = 0}(v(W_{t+s}) | \mathcal F_s).$$
Let $X_t$ be another brownian motion starting at $0$, and let $C_t = x+X_t$ Under the expectation, we can replace things with other things that are equal in distribution. Application of (6.4) thus gives:
$$ \E^{X_0 = W_s}(v(X_{t}))  = \E^{X_0 = W_s}(v(x+X_{t} - x) )  = \E^{X_0 =W_s}(v(C_t-x)) = \E^{C_0= B_s}(u(C_{t})) .$$

After relabelling, this is the required line.

Comment: So you use (6.4) to get $\E^{W_0 = 0}(v(W_{t+s}) | \mathcal F_s)=E^{X_0 =W_s}(v(X_t))$ and at the end replace $C$ with $B$ correct?

Comment: @takecare yes thats right. My opinion is that the notation  $\mathbb E^{B_s} (u(B_t))$ is mildly abusive, so i felt it was necessary to introduce $X$ and $C$.

Comment: Yes thank you, your answer makes everything clear. So this solution actually demonstrates that (6.4) holds wherever the Brownian motion starts at right? Can you please take a look at this question as well? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341044/question-about-the-proof-of-the-brownian-motion-being-a-strong-markov-process-fr

Comment: @takecare yes to the first; to the second, I don't have time right now to actually check if I can do it but my guess is that you can first prove everything holds for $\text{min}(\sigma , T)$, with $T>0$ arbitrary. Then try to apply a limit theorem like DCT?